# Опечатка на странице Справка -> Что такое отклонённые тревоги и что с ними делать?

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

Нашел опечатку на странице [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags).

Текущий текст, опечатку выделил:

> Проблема могла относиться к числу тех, с которыми вы могли бы справиться самостоятельно (например, вы отметили неправильный ответ тревогой, против которого **моли** бы проголосовать или улучшить его правкой).